# Display the popup once per page for the WordPress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup

I was trying to display the popup once per page for the WordPress site. 
I am using custom-jquery for this, here it is

```
 if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
    }
```

But it is working only for per session.
How to display the popup once per page?

Comment: Could you just set the localstate to something other than shown on page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to store URL's visited also.

This can be done in one big object that you use `JSON.stringify()` to store and `JSON.parse()` to retrieve

Could try something like:

```
var pageViews = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pageViews') || '{}'),
    url = location.href;

if(!pageViews[url]){
   // show your popup now 

   //and store this url
   pageViews[url] = true;
   localStorage.setItem('pageViews', JSON.stringify(pageViews ));
}
```

Comment: thanks Charlie, i tried the your code it is not displaying the popup on any page, do i need to set pageviews?

Comment: any errors in browser console? Note I did find a bug I fixed about 20 minutes ago

Comment: i tried your new code but it is not displaying the popup on any page  and there is no error in browser console.

Comment: sorry, i was using a condition for a page, your code is working now, you made my day... thanks a lot charlie.. thank you so much

Comment: Hello Charlie, is there any alternative for localStorage.getItem, it is not working in IE11.

Comment: no reason it shouldn't work in IE. What errors do you get?